# Erro de lógica em jogo da velha em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou aprendendo JavaScript e quero fazer um jogo da velha para treinar.O jogo não está funcionando e creio que possa ser um erro de lógica.

```js
  

function verificar(elemento) {
  var teste = document.getElementById(elemento).innerHTML;

  if (teste == "") {
    teste = "X";
  } else {
    teste = "Y";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 130px;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: solid green 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab" id="q1" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q2" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q3" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q4" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q5" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q6" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q7" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q8" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q9" onlick="verificar(this.id);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Primeiro, erro de sintaxe. É `onclick`, não `onlick` (ninguém quer lamber ninguém aqui, quer?), faltou um `c` em todos os seus elementos. Segundo, erro de lógica, você atribui X/Y para `teste` que é uma variável local na função, mas isso não vai alterar o seu elemento. Você precisa fazer algo como `document.getElementById...innerHTML = teste`

Comment: Mesmo com as dicas do Anderson seu código não vai funcionar como espera. Depois que ele sair do **if** pela primeira vez permanecerá sempre no **else**.

Answer (score 2):

Corrigindo apenas o que você já montou.

```js
function verificar(elemento) {
  if(elemento.innerHTML == "") {
    elemento.innerHTML = "X";
  } else {
    elemento.innerHTML = "Y";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 130px;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: solid green 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab" id="q1" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q2" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q3" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q4" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q5" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q6" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q7" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q8" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
  <div class="tab" id="q9" onclick="verificar(this);"></div>
</div>
```

Primeiro, como apontado pelo Anderson, você escreveu "onlick" ao invés de `onclick`. Também deixei seu código um pouco mais simples tirando o `this.id` e substituindo por apenas `this` que irá passar a div inteira pra função, ai é só se referir a ela por elemento sem ter que fazer nenhum tipo de query pelo DOM. Outra coisa apontada pelo Anderson nos comentários é que você estava modificando o valor da variável e não do `innerHTML` do elemento, por isso não estava saindo como queria.

Existem mais problemas nesse jogo para ser realmente um jogo da velha, como por exemplo, ao clicar num quadrado já com X ele se torna Y, mas não retorna para X se clicado de novo, fora que o jogo não deveria permitir que alguém clicasse num quadrado já ocupado. Também precisa ser feita a validação se a pessoa ganhou, perdeu, ou se deu empate.

Comment: "(...)você estava modificando o valor da variável e não do innerHTML do elemento".Eu só não entendi essa parte,cara.A variável é igual ao innerHTML,portanto o valor do innerHTML não deveria ser modificado também?

Comment: Não. A variável PEGOU o valor que estava no innerHTML e colocou dentro dela. É a mesma coisa que você fazer duas variáveis, igualar a segunda variável com a primeira, e ai modificar a segunda. A primeira não vai mudar, só a segunda.

Comment: Vou deixar um pouco mais fácil pra você entender.

Se você fizer `var teste = document.getElementById('id');` a variável vai apontar pro elemento.
Se você fizer `var teste = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;`  o método `innerHTML` irá retornar um valor que está no elemento, não irá te retornar o elemento. Nesse caso, a variável só tem um valor de string vazia (no seu caso).

Comment: @LuizAntônio sobre essa sua dúvida, recomendo que leia sobre *atribuição por cópia* e *atribuição por referência*. Entendendo a diferença entre elas entenderá porque as modificações na variável não são refletidas no elemento.